# System apps in Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-8.0-oreo

To add a system app in Android 7 and older versions it was sufficient to add .apk in system/app folder, but now it looks like it doesn't work. Did anyone encounter such a problem and what is a possible fix? The device I am dealig with is Nexus 5X.